# Do the words "Shema" and "Shem" come from the same root? And, if so, does this have significance in Jewish thought?

Tags: words

I surprisingly wasn't able to answer this through web searching.  I'm just curious if the multiple meanings of "shema" (hear, listen, obey), have implications for how people's names were thought of.

Comment: According to Ernest Klein's dictionary, they come from different roots with Sh'ma from earlier words related to hearing and shem to other words referring to name and possibly from roots meaning "to brand" (as in, cattle).

Answer (score 5):

I doubt it. "Shem" is a two-letter noun, and I don't think it ever gets "verbed" -- *to name something* in Hebrew always uses the word "to call", off the top of my head. "Shema" is a three-letter root, whose final letter, 'ayin, is pretty firmly fixed. (It's not one that easily gets taken away or added depended on conjugation.) (If you don't notice that final letter in *Shema*, that's because the 'Ayin is actually a fricative that became silent in many pronunciations.)